# How to use a bash script to execute python.py application followed by simulated user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script that will enable me to test a python application by applying varying inputs to the python application.

My goal is to do the following:

1. execute my python application   ie. `python3 mycode.py`
2. the python code is designed to wait for user input followed by the enter key.
   The bash script supplies the input and the enter key.
3. repeat this as many times as I want with whatever varying inputs that I hard code into the script.

I've spent a lot of time searching through prior questions on this topic and trying to adapt prior answers to this task but nothing seems to quite work.

I can execute the python application. But then my problem lies in getting the script to enter the user input. My bash script just pauses and waits for me to enter input.

The python code `mycode.py` is as follows:

```
        reader = sys.stdin
        word = reader.readline()
        print(word)
```

My trouble seems to be getting the bash script to pass my input argument to python `readline()`

My bash script is written as follows:

```
        #!/bin/bash
        python3 mycode.py
        read
```

I also tried using `python3 mycode.py &` to return control from python back to the bash script
to get it to take the hard coded user input but that didn't work either. I've also tried using `echo` and `$1`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:
turns out that `python3 mycode.py <<< 'somestring'` works really well if anyone is interested in the future.

Comment: @Allen : Your bassh `read` command reads from stdin, and your Python `readline` reads from stdin. There is nothing in your code which would stuff things into stdin. Actually, I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Describe, how you actually run your code (in particular your bash program), and what behaviour you want to see.

Comment: Right now, the only thing I'm trying to understand is how to get the bash script to (1) execute the python application described above (which I've been able to successfully do), and (2) stuff a hard coded string into stdin so it can be printed by the python application.
I figured read wouldn't work but I had already tried echo with no success.

Comment: `echo foo | python3 mycode.py`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `echo` doesn't work?

```sh
# cat foo.py
import sys
reader = sys.stdin
word = reader.readline()
print(word[::-1])
```

```sh
# echo 'foo' | python3 foo.py
oof
```

That being said, if you plan on making a larger-scale project I would highly recommend disentangling your input (and probably output) from stdout/stdin, so you can do these kinds of tests directly in python.

Comment: Right. I'm just trying to pass a string, abcd, for example and the script does not pass that to the python application. Maybe I'm not using it correctly.

I'm just doing `echo abcd`

BTW, I want to use this script for testing c and c++ code as well just by making simple changes to it.

Comment: What OS are you on?  What does `echo 'foo' | python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.readline())'` show?

Comment: It just prints 'foo' with a line feed after that.  And then returns to the bash prompt.

Comment: And I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Allan so it works.  Do `echo abcd | yourpython`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash v4 or greater you probably want to use coprocesses, using the 'coproc' command.
If your sole goal is to test the python however, why not have a look at pytest, and read up on monkey patch.

Comment: I would like to also be able to use the bash script to test c and c++ applications as just by making simple modifications.